# How to get a client IP address from a specific network?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, http, linux-networking

I have a condition to filtering IP address from client, and I just have their IP network like this `1.1.0.0/17`. If some client from this network will be filtered as special user on my website. And I also use php as web service language.

In case client who have `IP 1.1.4.24` will be automatically logged to databases.

Can someone tell me some way?

Comment: Maybe the following article might be of some use : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php

Answer (score 0):

So I assume you are looking for a php solution?
In that case you will need something like this:

```
function get_ip_address() {
    // check for shared internet/ISP IP
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }

    // check for IPs passing through proxies
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        // check if multiple ips exist in var
        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], ',') !== false) {
            $iplist = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
            foreach ($iplist as $ip) {
                if (validate_ip($ip))
                    return $ip;
            }
        } else {
            if (validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
                return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
    }
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP'];
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];

    // return unreliable ip since all else failed
    return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

function validate_ip($ip) {
if (strtolower($ip) === 'unknown')
    return false;

// generate ipv4 network address
$ip = ip2long($ip);

// if the ip is set and not equivalent to 255.255.255.255
if ($ip !== false && $ip !== -1) {
    // make sure to get unsigned long representation of ip
    // due to discrepancies between 32 and 64 bit OSes and
    // signed numbers (ints default to signed in PHP)
    $ip = sprintf('%u', $ip);
    // do private network range checking
    if ($ip >= 0 && $ip <= 50331647) return false;
    if ($ip >= 167772160 && $ip <= 184549375) return false;
    if ($ip >= 2130706432 && $ip <= 2147483647) return false;
    if ($ip >= 2851995648 && $ip <= 2852061183) return false;
    if ($ip >= 2886729728 && $ip <= 2887778303) return false;
    if ($ip >= 3221225984 && $ip <= 3221226239) return false;
    if ($ip >= 3232235520 && $ip <= 3232301055) return false;
    if ($ip >= 4294967040) return false;
}
return true;
 }
```

Now you only need to call $ip = get_ip_address();

I need to tell you that THIS IS **EXTREMELY DANGOROUS** to give people access based on ip's!

Comment: hello,sorry for late respons.thanks before for sharing your experience.why you said it is too dangerous ? can you tell me ?

Comment: ip-addresses can be easily spoofed that's why. It's the same as giving people acces on mac-addresses, you can easily spoof them.

Comment: fyi https://moviecode.tumblr.com/post/146093203920/from-csi-cyber-season-2-episode-6-the-hacker

Comment: Aren't you concerned this code might remotely control a vehicle somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what resources you have available to you, but there are devices that accomplish this based on the identity of the user logging in. For example, Cisco ASA Firewalls have an identity feature that picks up log-in events on a Microsoft Active Directory server and alerts the firewall of that user's IP address. Then you write ACL's based on username, as opposed to IP. It's not perfect but it works.

Cisco Identity Based Firewall: http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/products/collateral/security/asa-5500-series-next-generation-firewalls/at_a_glance_c45-675579.pdf

As it has been said, filtering on IP address alone is only a first step of security. It's easy to set a static IP, or even spoof an IP. You're going to want some authentication mechanism in there as well.

Comment: thanks for giving answer.but i need is PHP code to detect client IP for giving special features on my web to client from ISP.My companion is co-operate with some ISP.then the ISP's giving their network and subnet.so i can give the client special feature based on client IP  from that ISP

Comment: Ah I didn't realize that. Best of luck finding your PHP solution.